DirectX12のフルスクリーンの処理について
DirectX12でフルスクリーンを実装しようと思いマイクロソフト社のサンプル D3D12Fullscreen を参考に実装していました。
自身のプロジェクトで、サンプルの「Alt+Enter」でのフルスクリーンを実行する
Win32Application::ToggleFullscreenWindow の処理の pSwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput) でOutputのでデータが取得でず、例外処理を出し、システムのフルスクリーンのサイズデータを取得しているようです。
確認したいのです、 SwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput) の処理は必要なのでしょうか？
フルスクリーンのサイズを取得できる方法が別にあるなら必要なしでしょうか？
また、 D3D12Fullscreen::OnKeyDown のメンバ関数で m_tearingSupport がFALSEの場合は IDXGISWapChain::SetFullscreen を呼ぶようです。
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING とはどのようなものなのでしょうか？
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING に対応していないと IDXGISWapChain::SetFullscreen を呼ばないといけないのでしょうか？
void Win32Application::ToggleFullscreenWindow(IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain)
{
    if (m_fullscreenMode)
    {
        // Restore the window's attributes and size.
        SetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_STYLE, m_windowStyle);
        
        SetWindowPos(
            m_hwnd,
            HWND_NOTOPMOST,
            m_windowRect.left,
            m_windowRect.top,
            m_windowRect.right - m_windowRect.left,
            m_windowRect.bottom - m_windowRect.top,
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the old window rect so we can restore it when exiting fullscreen mode.
        GetWindowRect(m_hwnd, &m_windowRect);

        // Make the window borderless so that the client area can fill the screen.
        SetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_STYLE, m_windowStyle & ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME));

        RECT fullscreenWindowRect;
        try
        {
            if (pSwapChain)
            {
                // Get the settings of the display on which the app's window is currently displayed
                ComPtr<IDXGIOutput> pOutput;
                ThrowIfFailed(pSwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput));
                DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC Desc;
                ThrowIfFailed(pOutput->GetDesc(&Desc));
                fullscreenWindowRect = Desc.DesktopCoordinates;
            }
            else
            {
                // Fallback to EnumDisplaySettings implementation
                throw HrException(S_FALSE);
            }
        }
        catch (HrException& e)
        {
            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);

            // Get the settings of the primary display
            DEVMODE devMode = {};
            devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
            EnumDisplaySettings(nullptr, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode);

            fullscreenWindowRect = {
                devMode.dmPosition.x,
                devMode.dmPosition.y,
                devMode.dmPosition.x + static_cast<LONG>(devMode.dmPelsWidth),
                devMode.dmPosition.y + static_cast<LONG>(devMode.dmPelsHeight)
            };
        }

        SetWindowPos(
            m_hwnd,
            HWND_TOPMOST,
            fullscreenWindowRect.left,
            fullscreenWindowRect.top,
            fullscreenWindowRect.right,
            fullscreenWindowRect.bottom,
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE);


        ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }

    m_fullscreenMode = !m_fullscreenMode;
}


サマリー

SwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput) の処理は必要？

フルスクリーンサイズの取得には IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput の使用が推奨されます。しかし、これが失敗する場合にはシステムの主ディスプレイ設定をフォールバックとして使用することができます。


DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING とはどのようなものか？

垂直同期（V-Sync）を無視してスワップチェーンのフレームを提示することを許可するフラグです。


DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING がFALSEのときにIDXGISWapChain::SetFullscreen を呼ぶのはなぜ？

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING がFALSEのときは、テアリングを許可しない、つまり垂直同期（V-Sync）が有効な状態と考えられます。垂直同期が有効な場合、フレームの更新がディスプレイのリフレッシュレートと同期され、画面のちぎれ（テアリング）を防ぐので、IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen を使用することで、スムーズにフルスクリーンへの遷移が保証されます。



IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput の重要性
IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutputメソッドは、スワップチェーンに関連付けられている出力（ディスプレイ）を取得します。このメソッドは、アプリケーションが表示されている特定のモニターに関する情報を取得するのに有用です。特にマルチモニター環境では、どのモニターにフルスクリーンを適用するかを正確に制御するために重要です。
フルスクリーンのサイズを取得する別の方法として、システムの主ディスプレイ設定を使用することがあります（例えば、EnumDisplaySettings関数）。しかし、これは常にアプリケーションが現在表示されているモニターの設定を反映するわけではないため、GetContainingOutputが提供する正確さには及びません。
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING とは
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING は、垂直同期（V-Sync）を無視してスワップチェーンのフレームを提示することを許可するフラグです。これにより、高リフレッシュレートのディスプレイでの性能が向上し、画面のちぎれ（tearing）が発生することがありますが、遅延が少なくなるという利点があります。
IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen の使用条件
m_tearingSupport が FALSE の場合に IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen を呼ぶ理由は、テアリングを許可しない環境でフルスクリーンモードを強制的に有効にするためです。もしテアリングが許可されていれば、フルスクリーンモードの遷移がよりスムーズに、または異なる方法で行われる可能性があります。
「システムの主ディスプレイ設定」によるフルスクリーンサイズの取得
IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput の呼び出しが失敗した場合、つまり特定の出力（ディスプレイ）に関連付けられた情報が取得できない場合、フルスクリーンのサイズや位置を決定するために「システムの主ディスプレイ設定」をフォールバック（代替手段）として使用する方法について解説します。
システムの主ディスプレイ設定を使用する方法

EnumDisplaySettings 関数の使用:
Windows APIには、EnumDisplaySettings 関数があり、これを使用してディスプレイの設定情報を取得することができます。この関数は、指定されたディスプレイデバイスに対するディスプレイモードに関する情報を取得します。

引数:

lpszDeviceName: 取得したいディスプレイデバイスの名前。nullptr を指定すると、主ディスプレイデバイスの設定が取得されます。
iModeNum: 取得したいディスプレイモードのインデックス。ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS を指定すると、現在のディスプレイモードが取得されます。
lpDevMode: DEVMODE 構造体のポインタ。この構造体にディスプレイモードの情報が格納されます。


DEVMODE 構造体:
この構造体は、ディスプレイの解像度（dmPelsWidth、dmPelsHeight）、色深度（dmBitsPerPel）、リフレッシュレート（dmDisplayFrequency）などの情報を含んでいます。



フルスクリーンのウィンドウ位置とサイズの設定:
DEVMODE 構造体から取得した解像度情報を基に、フルスクリーンウィンドウの位置とサイズを設定します。例えば、dmPelsWidth と dmPelsHeight を使用して、ウィンドウの新しい座標を SetWindowPos 関数で設定します。


フォールバックの使用例
以下は、IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput の呼び出し後の例外処理として、EnumDisplaySettings を使用して主ディスプレイの設定をフォールバックとして取得する例です。
RECT fullscreenWindowRect;
try {
    // 通常の処理...
    ComPtr<IDXGIOutput> pOutput;
    ThrowIfFailed(pSwapChain->GetContainingOutput(&pOutput));
    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc;
    ThrowIfFailed(pOutput->GetDesc(&desc));
    fullscreenWindowRect = desc.DesktopCoordinates;
}
catch (HrException& e) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);

    // フォールバックとして主ディスプレイの設定を取得
    DEVMODE devMode = {};
    devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    if (EnumDisplaySettings(nullptr, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode)) {
        fullscreenWindowRect = {
            0,
            0,
            static_cast<LONG>(devMode.dmPelsWidth),
            static_cast<LONG>(devMode.dmPelsHeight)
        };
    }
}

SetWindowPos(...);

この方法により、GetContainingOutput が失敗した場合でも、アプリケーションは主ディスプレイの現在の設定を基にフルスクリーンウィンドウを適切に設定することが可能となります。

回答ありがとうございます。
確認したい点があるのですが、フルスクリーンの情報を「EnumDisplaySetting」などの方法で取得できるのであれば、
「IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen」などは使用しなくても問題ないのでしょうか？

フルスクリーンの情報を「EnumDisplaySetting」などの方法で取得できるのであれば、 「IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen」などは使用しなくても問題ないです。
IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreen を呼ばない場合、フルスクリーンモードへの遷移は、ウィンドウスタイルの変更や位置調整など、アプリケーション側で手動で行う必要があります。この手法は、いわゆる「ボーダレスフルスクリーン」や「フェイクフルスクリーン」とも呼ばれ、実際にはフルスクリーンAPIを使わずにウィンドウを画面全体に広げる方法です。

回答ありがとうございます。とても参考になりました。
